Hierarchical linear models for continuous outcomes
I aim to investigate the relationship between a single measurement of a continuous outcome and the presence of an intervention. Given that multiple hospitals recruited participants for the study, I recognize the need to employ a hierarchical or multi-level modeling approach.
what kind of model are the most suitable and how to do it using sas?
I tried to calculate lsmeans for each of the groups (intervention/no intervention) but I am not convinced about that using the proc glimmix procedure.
